# Login screen doesn't support dual monitors

Tags: greeter, resolution, wallpaper

When I log in to ElementaryOS, my wallpaper spans as expected because of the tweaks I installed. However, the login screen show mirrors the displays and doesn't account for different screen resolutions. When I log in, the screen flashes multiple times as if I had just plugged in the VGA cable. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-greeter/+bug/1355561) and the only way around it is likely to fix the bug. This is not necessarily true, but most likely is seeing as it appears to affect all installations with multiple, variant screen resolutions. Seeing as the burden of proof is always on the claimant, and I see no evidence that there would be a solution to this, I am going to close this as a duplicate of a bug report.